# C# Windows Form Application - How to get Radio Button to prompt text to appear in a Listbox upon clicking a Button?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2017

I have a Windows Form Application in Microsoft Visual Studio 2017, and for the design of that Form, I have three Radio Buttons (in a Group Box), a Button, a Textbox and a List Box. It looks like this:

[image: Windows Form]

How can I make it so that, when one of the Radio Buttons are selected, it will display the name of it in the Textbox next to where it says "Required Room Size", and display in the Listbox along with a price next to it. Don't worry, I already have the prices allocated to each Radio Button (Single = $80.00, Double = $110.00, Triple = $140.00), and I know that you are supposed to use "t\t\" in order to create a column in the Listbox, I'm just not sure how you are supposed to get text to display in said Listbox once prompted to do so by clicking a Button.

TL;DR - How do you make it so that when you select a Radio Button and **then** press a standard Button, it will display in both a Textbox and a Listbox?

Comment: You can append the text to the list box.

Comment: how did you make that required rooms size show what option you had selected? It's the same concept you will just concatenate the strings involved.

Comment: you should use the Radio Button event ValueChanged. So when the value of the radiobutton changes , the event is triggered.The same should be done for the button, (you should use the Click event)

Answer (score 0):

A radiobutton doesn't know that it is clicked unless you add an eventhandler to it.
This can be accomplished by doing the following.

```
RadioButton1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radioButtons_CheckedChanged);
```

Everytime a RadioButton gets checked or unchecked, the radioButtons_CheckChanged method will execute.
In the method you can set the TextBox.Text property.

```
TextBox1.Text = RadioButton1.Text;
```

Another way to do this is, is to loop through the radiobuttons and look for the radiobutton that has been checked. 
When the selected radiobutton has been found you can copy the text of the radiobutton into the textbox.

```
Button1_Click(RoutedEventArgs e, object o)
{
    if(RadioButton1.Checked) # Single Room
    {
        TextBox1.Text = RadioButton1.Text;
    }
    if(RadioButton2.Checked) # Double Room
    {
        TextBox1.Text = RadioButton2.Text;
    }
    if(RadioButton3.Checked) # Triple room
    {
        TextBox1.Text = RadioButton3.Text;
    }
}
```

It's up to you how you want to check which of radiobuttons has been checked.
But these are some of the ways it can achieved.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I was able to try this and got the text from the Radio Button to display in the Textbox properly. I was unaware that ".Text" could be added to the end of Radio Button names like so, but that was very helpful.

Since completing this, I've also figured out that where it says "RadioButton1.Text", you can also add text enclosed in quotation marks to achieve pretty much the same result.

Comment: Yes, as long as the value is between double quotation marks it will be seen as a string value. This way you can assign it to a text property of an object. If you want to learn more about the language and it's keywords. I advice you to do some more tutorials. There are some excellent one's available for free on MSDN.